# object reference not set to an instance of an object Inserting database sql array

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How can i insert array textbox in database?I have to save each newboxes in access and it should be in different row..It has an error object reference not set to an instance of an object when saving the data

> ```
> Public Class Form1
>     Dim boxes As New List(Of TextBox)
> ```
>
> Dim combo As New List(Of ComboBox)
>
> ```
>     Private Sub Addbuttons(buttonCount As Integer)
>         Dim newbox As TextBox   Dim newcombo As ComboBox
>
>         For i As Integer = 1 To buttonCount
>             newbox = New TextBox
>             newbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(575, 35)
>             newbox.Location = New Drawing.Point(10, 10 + 35 * (i - 1))
>             newbox.Name = "TextBox" & i
>             newbox.Text = newbox.Name
>             'connect it to a handler, save a reference to the array and add it to the form controls
>             boxes.Add(newbox)
>             Me.Controls.Add(newbox)
>         Next  For i As Integer = 1 To buttonCount
>         newcombo = New ComboBox
>         newcombo.Size = New Drawing.Size(57, 20)
>         newcombo.Location = New Drawing.Point(864, 531 + 70 * (i - 1))
>         combo.Add(newcombo)
>         Me.Controls.Add(newcombo)
>     Next
>     End Sub
>     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>         Addbuttons(Val(TextBox1.Text))
>     End Sub
>     Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>         addbuyer()
>     End Sub
>    Private Sub addbuyer()
>     Dim newbox As TextBox
>       Try
>         datab = " Insert INTO sample (sample1,sample2) values ( '" & newbox.Text & "','" & newqty.Text & "')"
>         connDB()
>         cmd = New OleDbCommand(datab, conn)
>         Dim i As Integer
>         i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
>         If i > 0 Then
>             '  MsgBox("Added SUccesfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Confirmation")
>
>
>         Else
>             MsgBox("Failed Adding", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Alert!")
>         End If
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         MsgBox(ex.Message)
>     Finally
>         cmd.Dispose()
>         conn.Close()
>
>     End Try
> End Sub
>
> End Class
> ```

Comment: what value you ware expected to give in `values ( '" &  & "')"`

Comment: Textboxes are objects, you can save the essential properties to a table, or serialize them and save the result, but you cant convert them to a byte array and back.

Comment: So is there no way i can save what i input in those newbox

Comment: So you want to save whats IN the textboxes or the textbox controls???  `How can i insert array textbox in database` sounds like you want to save the controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `addbuyer`, `Dim newbox As TextBox` is nothing and that's the cause of the error.

You added all the textbox controls to `boxes` so you need to loop thru that when you insert into the DB. One way to do it is by looping and passing each textbox by reference:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  For Each t As TextBox In boxes
      addbuyer(t)
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub addbuyer(ByRef newbox As TextBox)       
    Try
        datab = " Insert INTO sample (sample1) values ( '" & newbox.Text & "')"
        connDB()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(datab, conn)
        Dim i As Integer
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Added SUccesfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Confirmation")


        Else
            MsgBox("Failed Adding", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Alert!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```