# Insert array of two dims as list of textbox and combobox in MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How can I insert array textbox and combobox in database? I have to save each newboxes and newcombo in Access and it should be in a different row. It has an error object reference not set to an instance of an object when saving the data

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim form As New Form    
    Dim boxes As New List(Of TextBox)
    Dim combo As New List(Of ComboBox)



    Private Sub Addbuttons(ByVal buttonCount As Integer)
        Dim newbox As TextBox
          Dim newcombo As ComboBox

        For i As Integer = 1 To buttonCount
            newbox = New TextBox
            newbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(533, 50)
            newbox.Location = New Drawing.Point(227, 531 + 70 * (i - 1))
            newbox.Name = ""
            newbox.Text = newbox.Name
            'connect it to a handler, save a reference to the array and add it to the form controls
            boxes.Add(newbox)
            Me.Controls.Add(newbox)

        Next


            For i As Integer = 1 To buttonCount
                newcombo = New ComboBox
                newcombo.Size = New Drawing.Size(57, 20)
                newcombo.Location = New Drawing.Point(864, 531 + 70 * (i - 1))
                combo.Add(newcombo)
                Me.Controls.Add(newcombo)
            Next

    End Sub


    'Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    'End Sub



    'Private Sub btnitem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnitem.Click
    '    Addbuttons(Val(txtitem.Text))
    'End Sub

    Private Sub loaduom(ByRef newcombo As ComboBox)
        Try

            datab = "Select uom from uom"
            connDB()
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(datab, conn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            newcombo.Items.Clear()

            Do While dr.Read = True
                ' txtdepartadd.Items.Add(dr("Departmentname"))
                newcombo.Items.Add(dr(0))


            Loop

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub loading()
        For Each uomlo As ComboBox In combo
            loaduom(uomlo)
        Next
    End Sub

    'Private Sub loaduom()
    '    Throw New NotImplementedException
    'End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim msgboxresponse As MsgBoxResult

        msgboxresponse = MsgBox("Are You Sure of the number of Item you choose?Please Check Again", _
                                    MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, Me.Text)
            If msgboxresponse <> MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        Else
            Addbuttons(Val(txtitem.Text))
            txtitem.Enabled = False
            Button1.Enabled = False
            loading()
            loadstat()
            Return
            End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub addbuyer(ByRef newbox As TextBox, ByRef newcombo As ComboBox)
        'Dim newbox As TextBox 
        'Dim newcombo as combobox
        Try
            datab = " Insert INTO sample (sample1,sample2) values ( '" & newbox.Text & "','" & newcombo.Text & "')"
            connDB()
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(datab, conn)
            Dim i As Integer
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Added SUccesfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Confirmation")
            Else
                MsgBox("Failed Adding", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Alert!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
        Dim buttonCount As Integer = Val(TextBox1.Text)

        'start from 0 because it's 0-based index
        For i As Integer = 0 To buttonCount - 1
            addbuyer(boxes(i), combo(i))
        Next
    End Sub    

End Class
```

Comment: didn't you ask this a couple of days ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642088/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-inserting-database-sql-arra/35643380#35643380

Comment: yeah but i add combobox and i cant use it in for each.now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it based on your current code

In `Button2_Click`:

1) Get the total # of controls

2) loop and call `addbuyer` passing the controls by reference

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim buttonCount As Integer = Val(txtitem.Text)

    'start from 0 because it's 0-based index
    For i As Integer = 0 To buttonCount - 1 
             addbuyer(boxes(i), combo(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

In `addbuyer`:

1) change `ByRef newbox As RichTextBox` to `ByRef newbox As TextBox`

2) comment out (or delete) the first two lines, they aren't needed

```
Private Sub addbuyer(ByRef newbox As TextBox, ByRef newcombo As ComboBox)
         'Dim newbox As TextBox 
         'Dim newcombo as combobox
           Try
             datab = " Insert INTO sample (sample1,sample2) values ( '" & newbox.Text & "','" & newcon.Text & "')"
            connDB()
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(datab, conn)
             Dim i As Integer
             i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
             If i > 0 Then
                 '  MsgBox("Added SUccesfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Confirmation")
             Else
                 MsgBox("Failed Adding", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Alert!")
             End If
         Catch ex As Exception
             MsgBox(ex.Message)
         Finally
             cmd.Dispose()
             conn.Close()
         End Try
     End Sub
```

Comment: Update your code above with your changes and tell me what error you're getting

Comment: i edit my code from above..there's no error when i add your code but its not saving in database

Comment: You changed your code, you were calling `AddButtons` with `Val(TextBox1.Text)`...so I used TextBox1 in my code...but now you're calling it with `Val(txtitem.Text)`. I updated my code above to use `txtitem`